# How to call a function after a for loop of ajax requests/this.setStates?

Tags: reactjs, ajax

I am making multiple ajax requests in a for loop and this.setState({bla bla}) in each ajax request. How do I run a callback function only after the **last** this.setState is completed, not every one?

```
getAllSongsFromPlaylists(token, playlists) {
    for (let i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++) {
   //console.log(id);
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/"+playlists[i]+"/tracks",
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: xhr => {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        },
        error: error => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        success: data => {
          // Checks if the data is not empty
          if(!data) {
            this.setState({
              no_data: true,
            });
            return;
          }

          var songs = this.state.songs; 
          for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            songs.add(data.items[i].track.name);
          }
        
  
        }
      });
    }
//I WANT A FUNCTION HERE THAT WILL ONLY RUN AFTER ALL THE AJAX CALLS ARE DONE 
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: You can use redux with saga middleware.